# Unable to load bookmarks list on emacs master

Tags: bookmarks, debug

Whenever I try to execute `bookmark-bmenu-list` (which loads the bookmarks file), I get the following error: `bmkp-multi-sort: Symbol’s function definition is void: bmkp-info-cp`.

I am running on emacs master build version: `GNU Emacs 26.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0, NS appkit-1504.83 Version 10.12.5 (Build 16F73)) of 2017-07-08` on Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: That `bmkp` stuff is from [BookmarkPlus](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus), right?

Comment: Yes bookmarkplus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Turned out there was a file `~/.emacs-bmk-bmenu-state.el`
that still contained the pesky symbol. I moved the file to a save directory, restarted Emacs, and now bookmark+ works again.

Comment: Yep. Sorry; this was my bad. I renamed `bmkp-info-cp` to `bmkp-info-node-name-cp` when I added `bmkp-info-position-cp`, without leaving the old name as an (obsolete) alias. And then I went on vacation... I've restored the old name as an alias now. Sorry for the trouble.